# Tier price slider

Tags: magento-1.7, catalog, price, tierprice, catalog-price-rules

I need one functionality for my magento project.
I needed slider for the product tier price.I need some thing like that

When

```
Qty is 10 price $10 per product
Qty is 11 to 99 price $9 per product
Qty is 100 to 999 price $8 per product
Qty is 1000 and above price $7 per product
```

i want to calculate this using price slider this facility available using tier price but i need slider for that for rich UI. like below

[image]

Is any one have a idea how can i apply slider or any extension is available for this functionality.

Please suggest me some good extension or code to apply. I search on google but not getting any proper solution. I hope that i find out it here.

Regards
Jalpesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long searching I got this [extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-units-and-quantities-5167.html) for the Product Quantity slider on the category page,Product detail page and cart page. And base on the Quantity it will count the price of the product. It works in the tier price as well as in the Configure product,Group Product and work for me perfectly.

I put answer of my Question because i think this will help to other who need same functionality as me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magehouse-free-price-slider-9130.html). This is a free and best among the available. If you can afford paid extensions, there are plenty of em.

So if you use the above extension:

1. modify Price.php in module Block\Catalog\Layer\Filter.
2. change setMinPrice() and setMaxPrice()

change `$this->_minPrice = $this->_productCollection->getFirstItem()->getPrice();`

to `$this->_minPrice = $this->_productCollection->getFirstItem()->getTierPrice();`

> note: didn't test it. If you have problems revert back.

Comment: Extension is not as i need but thanks for your effort. I need this extension for product detail page @shathish

Comment: okay u want it in product view page, is it?

Comment: Yes i want this functionality in product view page @Shathish